# How to show truncated form of large pandas dataframe after style.apply?

Tags: pandas

Normally, a relatively long dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(100,2)))
df
```

will display a truncated form in jupyter notebook like

[image]

With head, tail, ellipsis in between and row column count in the end.
However, after style.apply

```
def highlight_max(x):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v == x.max() else '' for v in x]
df.style.apply(highlight_max)
```

we got all rows displayed

[image]

Is it possible to still display the truncated form of dataframe after style.apply?

Comment: Why do you want to hide rows you highlighted?

Comment: @ScottBoston Because there are too many rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple like this?

```
def display_df(dataframe, function):
    display(dataframe.head().style.apply(function))
    display(dataframe.tail().style.apply(function))
    print(f'{dataframe.shape[0]} rows x {dataframe.shape[1]} columns')

display_df(df, highlight_max)
```

Output:

[image]

**** EDIT ****

```
def display_df(dataframe, function):
    display(pd.concat([dataframe.iloc[:5,:],
                       pd.DataFrame(index=['...'], columns=dataframe.columns),
                       dataframe.iloc[-5:,:]]).style.apply(function))
    print(f'{dataframe.shape[0]} rows x {dataframe.shape[1]} columns')

display_df(df, highlight_max)
```

Output:

[image]

The jupyter preview is basically something like this:

```
def display_df(dataframe):
    display(pd.concat([dataframe.iloc[:5,:],
                       pd.DataFrame(index=['...'], columns=dataframe.columns, data={0: '...', 1: '...'}),
                       dataframe.iloc[-5:,:]]))
```

but if you try to apply style you are getting an error (TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str') because it's trying to compare and highlight the string values '...'

Comment: That is a possible way, except it is not the default form with the ellipsis. Thank you +1

Comment: The pandas style method is supposed to be applied to the whole dataframe so that you can observe the highlighted values. Check my edited answer, this is the closest i could get to jupyter's preview.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output in a variable and then use `head` or `tail` on it. This gives you more control on what you display every time.

```
output = df.style.apply(highlight_max)
output.head(10)  # 10 -> number of rows to display
```

If you want to see more variate data you can also use `sample`, which will get random rows:

```
output.sample(10)
```

Comment: Hi, Carles Sala. Thank you for your answer. But I do not mean the head or sample. I mean the default truncated form that shows head, tail and basic info of rows and colums